# ColdFusion found 0 methods that match the provided arguments

Tags: java, .net, coldfusion

I'm trying to implement a .Net component in a Coldfusion application (this is on my development machine running CF 11.

I set up the object like this:

```
<cfset dll = ExpandPath('./com/Interop.CADXLib.dll')>
<cfobject class="CADXLib.CadX"  type=".NET"  name="cadx"  assembly="#dll#”>
```

That’s in my application.cfc, in the onRequestStart() method. Then in my index.cfm I call:

```
<cfdump var="#cadx#”>
```

The object dumps just fine. I can see all the internal methods, including the one I need to get things going, the OpenDesign() method, which (in theory) opens a local file and reads the contents.

So next I set the actual filename I want to access:

```
<cfset thisfile="1571269P01R01_ARTIOS.ARD">
<cfset thispath=getDirectoryfromPath(getCurrentTemplatePath())>
<cfset thisfile=thispath & thisfile>
```

This works, and outputting “thistfile” gives me the correct path location.  So now I call the actual method:

```
<cfset result=cadx.OpenDesign(thisfile,0)>
```

That’s where I get stuck. I get this error:

> Either there are no methods with the specified method name and argument types or the OpenDesign method is overloaded with argument types that ColdFusion cannot decipher reliably. ColdFusion found 0 methods that match the provided arguments. If this is a Java object and you verified that the method exists, use the javacast function to reduce ambiguity.

I try the javacast function:

```
<cfset result=cadx.OpenDesign(JavaCast("string",thisfile),JavaCast("int",0))>
```

Same error. Method not found. But based on the dump, the method is clearly there.

Has anyone encountered this or something similar?

Comment: Is there a published API for this CadX thing? Or if not, what is the *exact* method signature of the method you're trying to call? What you're trying to do looks right.

Comment: Can you call the method from a .net console application?

Comment: The documentation for the API is pretty slim unfortunately.  In the dump of the cadx object, the method shows up as:

`OpenDesign(java.lang.String, short)`    

I'm trying to figure out if I can call it from a console application in VB now.  I've never done that before, so it's a learning process.  I don't have a working example in .net unfortunately.

Comment: Did you try JavaCast("short",0)) instead of "int"?

Comment: Yeah, I tried all kinds of variations of javacast. I'm beginning to think the problem is the component itself. The vendor is being very balky about providing any information, and I don't have any problems instantiating any other objects

Comment: Can I ask is this the FIRST .NET object you have used in this application? CF creates a proxy jarfile (dotNetCoreProxy.jar) that has access to the framework. Sometimes mixing "bitness" causes issues like this. See this article: http://www.coldfusionmuse.com/index.cfm/2011/1/3/coldfusion.NET.Integration.dotNetCoreProxy

Comment: @MarkAKruger this is the first one.  That looks really promising, going to give it a try. Will report back.